# WPF Grid Row maximum height but resizable via GridSplitter

Tags: wpf, grid, expander, gridsplitter

I would like to have an expander at the bottom which should be resizable via a grid splitter .

But not with auto height in the content (because the included data grid will need the whole window).

What is the resolution?

My Code: ...

```
<Expander Grid.Row="1" ExpandDirection="Up" IsExpanded="True">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition MinHeight="4" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Height="4" ResizeDirection="Rows"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext"/>
                <DataGrid .../>
            </Grid>
```

I also tried to set the Maximum Height of the RowDefinition --> The content will not be stretched after resizing the GridSplitter.

Comment: Why you put GridSplitter inside Expander Content, if you wish to resize the Expander ? Please study about Controls behavior and how to arrange them on UI.

Comment: The GridSplitter is inside Expander Content because the content of the expanded Expander should be resizeable. After pressing the Expander the content should be collapsed.

Comment: Please do some reading of good WPF books about how controls in WPF work.

Comment: nice help for probably one property to be set...

Answer (score 0):

I used following code behind to solve the issue:

```
<Grid>.RowDefinitions[1].Height = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Pixel);
```